# Pass value of textbox to first empty row of specific column in datagrid WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating WPF application running c# . On one tab item I have checkbox textbox and button on another tab I have datagrid. ComboBox contains column header names. Once button is clicked it should enter text from textbox to first empty cell of column defined by ComboBox.

My XAML :

```
<TabItem x:Name="INCTab" Header="Incident Log" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="CReatedTicketNumberLabel" Content="Created Ticket No." Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="640,308,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Userzalog" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="755,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="TicketType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Grid.Column="1" Margin="755,341,0,0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="TicketTypeLabel" Content="Created Ticket No." Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="640,338,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
                        <Button x:Name="AddToDailySheet" Content="Add to List" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="1075,313,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="AddToDailySheet_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                 <TabItem x:Name="ExcelTab" Header="Excel File">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="122*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="775*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="422*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <DataGrid x:Name="ExcelTikets1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="455" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1195"  SelectionUnit="Cell"  Margin="77,15,47,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RR}" Header="RR" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle >
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A9D08E" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RD}" Header="RD" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#92D050" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DI}" Header="DI" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A9D08E" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DU}" Header="DU" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#92D050" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RT}" Header="RT" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A9D08E" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RW}" Header="RW" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#92D050" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Info_only_ticket}" Header="Info only tickets" Width="120">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A9D08E" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SPEC_Tickets}" Header="SPEC Tickets" Width="120">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#92D050" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Escalations}" Header="Escalation" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A9D08E" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Duplicates}" Header="Duplicates" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#92D050" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Inbound_Calls_Created}" Header="inbound Calls Created" Width="120">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#A9D08E" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Modified_with_no_resolution}" Header="Modified with no resolution" Width="160">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC000"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#92D050" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>


                <TextBox x:Name="Datum" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="50,518,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Button x:Name="Createfile" Content="Create File" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="85,493,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Click="Createfile_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

My Code:

```
     private void LoadApp()
    {

        String name = sheet1.Text;
        string name2 = brojradnje1.Text;
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        "SCOLogTable.xlsx" +
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";


        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

        OleDbCommand oconn1 = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
       
        con.Open();


        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn1);
    

        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(data);


        dataGridView1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { Source = data });
        
        con.Close();

    }
    
    private void AddToDailySheet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Datum.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
         Clipboard.SetText(Userzalog.Text);
        MainTab.SelectedItem = ExcelTab;
        if ((ExcelTikets1.Items.Count > 0) &&
            (ExcelTikets1.Columns.Count > 0))
        {
            //Select the first column of the first item.
            ExcelTikets1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(ExcelTikets1.Items[0], ExcelTikets1.Columns[0]);
            ExcelTikets1.SelectedCells.Add(ExcelTikets1.CurrentCell);
            ExcelTikets1.BeginEdit();
         
        }

        Clipboard.GetText()

    }
```

Anyone has any suggestion on how to do this ?

Comment: You have the selected item of the ComboBox. Use this value to get the column of the DataTable and modify it. Todo  this you need to store the actual DataTable in a public property (to which you can also bind the DataGrid to).

Comment: I am new to WPF and C# so can you provide some example code on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The below example shows how to extract the first empty cell of a column. This code is based on your implementation style.

I highly recommend to take your time to look into data binding. You should not reference the controls directly. Rather should you bind properties of the controls to custom properties (preferably dependency properties when inside a control) in order to access the data. [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0) and [Dependency properties overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0)

```
private void InsertValueIntoFirstEmptyCell(string columnName, string newCellValue)
{
  var tableView = this.ExcelTikets1.ItemsSource as DataView;
  foreach (DataRowView rowView in tableView)
  {
    var currentCellValue = rowView[columnName] as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentCellValue))
    {
      rowView[columnName] = newCellValue;
      return;
    }
  }
}

private void AddToDailySheet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedColumnName = this.TicketType,SelectedItem as string;
  string newCellValue = this.Userzalog.Text;
  InsertValueIntoFirstEmptyCell(selectedColumnName, newCellValue);

  // Your code
}
```